# No signature in HelloSign signed document

Tags: signing, electronic-signature

I have this strange question regarding HelloSign, the answer to witch I was not able to find in their docs.

I have implemented the embed signing feature on my website with **`test mode on`.**

The signing process goes as it should via `POST /signature_request/create_embedded` request. The iFrame is opened, I put the signature and after I get the **SIGNED** event, I perform the `GET /signature_request/files/[:signature_request_id]` request to get signed document. The file is being downloaded and saved, and when I open it and compare with the file preview I have on HelloSign account, I see the many differences.

In my downloaded file there is the signature field added by HelloSign, but actually there is no signature inside. Also the additional page with transaction information does not exist.

Here is actually what I get in my pdf:

[image]

And this is what is contained in the file downloaded directly from HS admin:
[image]

Does this mean there was something wrong with downloaded doc, or is this just the test mode effect?

I hope I haven't completely misunderstood the signing feature...

Comment: This looks like a bug on our side. Can you email us at apisupport@hellosign.com with the detail of this signature request so we get this figured out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be waiting for the backend callback with the event signature_request_all_signed.

More info on handling callbacks can be found here: https://www.hellosign.com/api/eventsAndCallbacksWalkthrough

When a user signs a document, it takes a few seconds for the final PDF to be generated. If you request to download the file before then, you will get the file in the state before it is signed (i.e. in the same state as if you had downloaded the file before the user had signed). To be safe, wait for the signature_request_all_signed callback and then fetch the final PDF.

Comment: got the same answer to my email :)
will try, thanks.

Comment: Hey @Ben Dezile, I have implemented the event-based flow, but I can't get the event json. It says *'Events posted to your callback url will be formatted as a JSON string contained in the json POST param'*. But it doesn't say what's the param name. Even more. The Nodejs body parser can't find any paramenter for the callback request. There isn't anything neghther in request body, nor in request query params.